# AWS S3 content over VPN is not getting decompressed (gzip)

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, gzip

We have a client who is having difficulty viewing our content over their VPN. If they browse to the content it appears with all crazy characters. I think I have worked out its somthing to do with GZIP, possibly the header is being stripped out?

Example of what it looks like: http://temp.a2om.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/help.html
Note: i manually removed the header on that so you can see what it looks like for the client, and to help me diagnose the problem

However, the real files DO have the real headers, for example:
http://temp.a2om.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/works.html
This comes back with the headers
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch

Any ideas why this would do this over a VPN, is there anything we can do (apart from uploading uncompressed)

Headers from mine(bottom) client(top)
[image]

Many thanks

Comment: It shouldn't be VPN-related *per se* but they might have some kind of (primitive, imho) security system that manipulates http requests/responses.  The question that comes to my mind is, do **their** browsers send the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header and does it arrive at the web server?  There are test sites like http://www.xhaus.com/headers (selected randomly from a google search, no affiliation here) that display the request headers received by the web server (which could differ from what the browser sent, if there's some security mechanism manipulating traffic).  Results might be interesting.

Comment: so, it seems the clients browser is not seding accept-encoding at all - any reason why they would do this? Nothing I can do right?

Comment: I suspect the browser is sending it (you'll want to compare this result with what the browser tries to send) but it's being stripped by an intermediate "security" device on their side... meaning there's nothing you can do unless you can get whoever controls that hardware to make it behave a little more safely.